# Javascript Regular Expression for Zip fails

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to do US zip code validation using knockout validation pattern but no matter what I do it gives Please specify a valid zip i.e. the regular expression fails, Please help.

```
address().Zip.extend({
            required: true,
            pattern: {
                message: 'Please specify a valid zip',
                params: '/(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supply a RegEx literal instead, for example:

```
address().Zip.extend({
            required: true,
            pattern: {
                message: 'Please specify a valid zip',
                params: /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/
            }
        });
```